# Algorithm to convert directed acyclic graphs to sequences

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

If D depends on B and C which each depend on A, I want ABCD (or ACBD) as the result; that is generate a flat sequence from the graph such that all nodes appear before any of their descendants. For example, we may need to install dependencies for X before installing X.

What is a good algorithm for this?

Comment: You want a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sort)

Comment: @Heuster Please make it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In questions like this, terminology is crucial in order to find the correct links.

The dependencies you describe form a [*partially ordered set*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) (poset). Simply put, that is a set with an order operator, for which the comparison of some pairs might be undefined. In your example `B` and `C` are incomparible (neither `B` depends on `C`, nor `C` depends on `B`).

An *extension* of the order operator is one that respects the original partial order and adds some extra comparisons to previously incomparable elements. In the extreme: a *linear extension* leads to a total ordering. For every partial ordering [such an extension exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-extension_principle#Order-extension_principle).

Algorithms to obtain a linear extension from a poset are called [*topological sorting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Wikipedia provides the following very simple [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Algorithms):

```
L ← Empty list that will contain the sorted elements
S ← Set of all nodes with no incoming edges
while S is non-empty do
    remove a node n from S
    add n to tail of L
    for each node m with an edge e from n to m do
        remove edge e from the graph
        if m has no other incoming edges then
            insert m into S
if graph has edges then
    return error (graph has at least one cycle)
else 
    return L (a topologically sorted order)
```